# How can i search by tag name and if post published

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i have 2 problems;
the first one; How can i search by tag name tag model is manytomanyfield.
the last one; if post published,  show posts by tag name.
i take published posts using this code " post_list=Post.objects.published()".
However, i don't know how can i use filter and published

Models.py

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    tag_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class PostQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def active(self):
        return self.filter(status__in=[Post.STATUS_PUBLISHED])

    def published(self):
        return self.filter(status=Post.STATUS_PUBLISHED)


class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_DRAFT = 1
    STATUS_PUBLISHED = 2
    STATUSES = (
        (STATUS_DRAFT, 'Draft'),
        (STATUS_PUBLISHED, 'Published'),
    )
    category=models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    tag=models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Yazar",related_name='posts')
    title=models.CharField(max_length=120,verbose_name="Başlık")
    content=RichTextField(verbose_name="İçerik")
    created_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,verbose_name="Oluşturulma Tarihi")
    updated_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,verbose_name="Güncellenme Tarihi")
    image=models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=130,unique=True)
    status = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=STATUSES)
    objects = PostQuerySet.as_manager()
```

views.py

```
def post_index(request):
    #post_list=Post.objects.published().order_by('-created_date')
    post_list=Post.objects.published()
    query=request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        post_list=post_list.filter(
            Q(content__icontains=query)|
            Q(title__icontains=query) |
            Q(tag_name__icontains=query)| # doesn't work
            Q(user__first_name__icontains=query)).distinct()...
```

Comment: as williem suggested I do think you need to do `tag__name__icontains=query` instead of `tag_name__icontains=query`

Comment: Can you also post your `Tag` model please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `tag__tag_name` (with two consecutive underscores), and with `tag_name`, since that is the name of the field of your `Tag` model:

```
def post_index(request):
    #post_list=Post.objects.published().order_by('-created_date')
    post_list=Post.objects.published()
    query=request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        post_list=post_list.filter(
            Q(content__icontains=query)|
            Q(title__icontains=query) |
            Q(tag__tag_name__icontains=query)|
            Q(user__first_name__icontains=query)
        ).distinct()
```

I would however advice to rename your `tag = ManyToManyField(Tag)` to `tags = ManyToManyField(Tag)`, since a `ManyToManyField` results in a collection of objects, and thus a plular name is probably better.

Comment: Exception Type: FieldError
Exception Value: 
Related Field got invalid lookup: name

Comment: @Enes: does your `Tag` model has a `name` field?

Comment: And i forgot to add Model.py tag ; class Tag(models.Model):
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    tag_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)

Comment: @Enes: then it is `tag__tag_name`, but it might be better to drop the `tag_` prefix anyway.

Comment: Thanks it works :) And my last question how can i take published posts as like as post_list=Post.objects.published()

Comment: @Enes: but you are doing that already? `post_list=Post.objects.published()` is written two lines before the `if query`. We simply add an extra `.filter(..)` clause, so it will only show published posts.

Comment: i said for  post_list=post_list.filter(...). now i tried and properly :D thanks for the answers have a good day